# forEach() only returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I'm using a `forEach()` to iterate through an array. If I `console.log()` it, the correct objects appear in the console, but if I try to append via `innerHTML`, it just shows `undefined` on the page where the objects should be. Can anyone help me?

```js
const phoneNos = () => {
   dBase.name.phones.forEach(phone => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.contacts').innerHTML += '<span class="pnumber">' + phone + '</span>';
      console.log(phone);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.contacts')
    .forEach(c => c.innerHTML += '<span class="pnumber">' + phone + '</span>');
```

Comment: I doubt he really wants to append the same phone number to every contact.

Comment: He clearly wants to put multiple numbers into a single element. Not a single number into multiple elements. Why did this get upvotes?